# Variable substitution error in Pi-calculus

Tags: kframework

I am learning the language K, so I started a little implementation of the Pi-Calculus with K.
I can't figure out why my substitution `Q[Z/Y]` doesn't work in my program below.

My program is: `(m(z) . m ! z) | (m ! 4 . m(x))` (a ping/pong between two thread),  and with my K semantic below I get this output:

```
</thread> <thread>
    <k>
      m ! z ~> .
    </k>
  </thread> <thread>
    <k>
      m ( x ) ~> .
    </k>
```

But `z` is not substituted. I would expect this output:

```
</thread> <thread>
    <k>
      m ! 4 ~> .      <---The 2nd z take the value of 4
    </k>
  </thread> <thread>
    <k>
      m ( x ) ~> .
    </k>
```

Here is my K semantic for the Pi-calculus.
Notice that I use `x!y` instead of `x<y>` for the send construction.

```
require "substitution.md"

module PI-SYNTAX 
    imports DOMAINS-SYNTAX
    imports KVAR-SYNTAX

    syntax Val ::= KVar  [binder]
                | Int

    syntax Proc ::= "(" Proc ")"        [bracket]
                | Send
                | Receive
                | None
                | Replication
                > Proc "." Proc         [left]
                > Par

    syntax None ::= "None"

    syntax Par ::= Proc "|" Proc        [left]

    syntax Receive ::= Id "(" Val ")"   

    syntax Send ::= Id "!" Val

    syntax Replication ::= "!" Proc

endmodule

module PI
    imports PI-SYNTAX
    imports DOMAINS
    imports SUBSTITUTION

    syntax KResult ::= Int | Bool

      configuration <T color="yellow">
                        <thread multiplicity="*" type="Set" color="blue">
                            <k color="green"> $PGM:Proc </k>
                        </thread>
                    </T>

    // Parallel composition:
    rule <thread> <k> P1:Proc | P2:Proc => . ... </k> </thread>
        (.Bag => <thread> <k> P1 </k> </thread>)
        (.Bag => <thread> <k> P2 </k> </thread>)

    // Communicate reduction: x ! y . P | x(y) . Q => P | Q[z/y]
    rule
        <thread> ... <k> X:Id ! Y:Val . P:Proc => P </k> ... </thread>
        <thread> ... <k> X:Id ( Z:Val ) . Q:Proc => Q[Z/Y] </k> ... </thread>
endmodule
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what all is happening here, but at the very least, you shouldn't have the binder attribute on a subsort production to kvar. It's intended to be placed on a term that binds a variable during substitution like lambda or mu. With it being placed as it is now, it's either being ignored, or worse, it's causing undefined behavior in the interpreter because binders are intended to be placed on productions with at least two nonterminals. I'm not sure which it is, but either way, it doesn't have whatever meaning you intend it to have.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, it seems that am I looking for another behavior.